# require_once inside of a function

Tags: php, security

for self exercise and training I am building my own CMS from the ground up. Part of this exercise is to enable custom html, css templates

Security wise, is it better if I open the PHP template file with require_once inside of a function to protect outside variables like the Database Handler and such?

Or should I make this entirely diffrent than this?

Comment: I don't understand how `require_once` is related to functions?

Comment: if you use require_once inside of a function it "SEEMS" that only the variables defined in this function work

Comment: That's not `require_once` specific. That has to do with Variables scope and isn't bound to `require_once`. See http://php.net/variables.scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be utterly useless to `require_once()` an external file that defines variables within a function:

library.php:

```
<?php

if (!isset($counter)) {
   $counter = 0;
}

$counter++; // increments every time this file is included
echo "Counter is $counter\n";
```

maincode.php:

```
<?php

function foo() {
        require_once('library.php');
        echo "foo() has counter = $counter\n";
}

function bar() {
        require_once('library.php');
        echo "bar() has counter = $counter\n";
}

foo();
bar();
```

Results:

```
$ php maincode.php
Counter is 1
foo() has counter = 1
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: counter in maincode.php on line 10
bar() has counter =
```

`Include`d/`require`d files inherit the scope of the context they're executed in. When you do that `include` in a function, you get the function's context, and the variables become "local" variables within the function, and are destroyed when the function call returns.

And if you do the `_once()` variant, your file literally is included only **ONCE** for the entire lifetime of the script, leading to the warning above. The `require_once()` call in `bar()` didn't do anything, because the file had already been included previously within the `foo()` call. So it's not included, `$counter` never gets defined within `bar()`, and now nothing works.

You can, of course, simply use the plain `include()` and `require()` variants. But then the same problems hold - any variables defined within the included file are destroyed when the function exits. That means that things like database connections will also be destroyed and cleaned up - making it impossible to hold a transaction open across function calls.

Comment: Now knowing this I feel a lot smarter.
My goal on containing the included file within a function works which is great. On the opposite its bad to do it this way as you mentioned. Thanks for answering